# GitLab test coverage visualization is not working on a simple example

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, code-coverage, cobertura

I have created a very simple example: https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/gitlab-coverage.

Unfortunately gitlab does not show Cobertura coverage visualisation.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: python:3

stages:
- test

coverage:
  stage: test
  script:
  - pip install coverage
  - coverage run ./main.py
  - coverage report -m
  - coverage xml
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./coverage.xml
    reports:
      cobertura: ./coverage.xml
  only:
  - master
```

In logs I can see that coverage report is uploaded ([link](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/gitlab-coverage/-/jobs/1450561054)):

```
$ coverage run ./main.py
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s
OK
$ coverage report -m
Name      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------
main.py      26     12    54%   9-14, 20-25
---------------------------------------
TOTAL        26     12    54%
$ coverage xml
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:03
Uploading artifacts...
./coverage.xml: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... ok  id=1450561054 responseStatus=201 Created token=eZqc9KYb
Uploading artifacts...
./coverage.xml: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "cobertura" to coordinator... ok  id=1450561054 responseStatus=201 Created token=eZqc9KYb
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have filed [an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/336861) and solution was found. Here is the recap:

- I understood the feature wrong, it works only for MR changes, not on regular commits or in file explorer
- I missed that recently there was a rename from `master` to `main`, documenation examples were not updated and I copied that to my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, which prevented autostarting pipelines on commit

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at the sample project you created.

When looking at [the diff for the open MR](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/gitlab-coverage/-/merge_requests/4/diffs), I am able to see the coverage visualization. Here is a screenshot of the coverage visualization in sample project MR.

[image]

If you're still having issues, it would be great if you could open a [bug report](https://about.gitlab.com/submit-feedback/#reproducible-bugs) and share more details about your browser settings, etc so we can identify the cause of your issue.

Comment: I have filed an issue and we found the solution. Here is the recap:

- I understood the feature wrong, it works only for MR, not on regular commits or file explorer
- I missed that recently there was a rename from `master` to `main`, documenation examples were not updated and I copied that to my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, which prevented autostart on commit.
- the link to MR you provided was exactly the point when it started working

Sorry, I should have updated this stackoverflow question as well, my bad. Doing it now.

Many thanks, John, for taking a look and trying to help!

Comment: Hi! 
I would expect that the Tests tab wouldn't be empty as in the case of junit format. Yours and in my case as well, are empty.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't the test tab also show the tests like it does for the junit format?
[image]